# Can I install a plow on my stock Silverado?

Tags: winter, truck, frame, installation

I've got a Chevrolet Silverado 1500 LS 4x4, and I'd like to install a plow.  I want to avoid damaging the truck, as it's also my primary means of transportation.

Do I have to do anything to stiffen up the frame, or can I simply install the plow as is?

Is there anything else I have to worry about here (transmission wear, tire/suspension damage, etc.)?

Answer (score 6):

I plowed with a Chevy 1500 and a Ford F250. You could definitely feel the weight of the plow more on the smaller 1500 compared to the F250. The 1500 would squat quite a bit when the plow was lifted.

The plow (a Western brand) was professionally installed on both trucks, and the only issues we ever had were electrical with the plow controls, the same kind of trouble that is typical with trailer wiring--connections and wiring exposed to the weather are always problematic.

The 1500 with the Western plow did a fine job. The truck eventually had some noise from the final drive/differential, but it had been used for professional plowing and landscaping for years.

I think if you have the plow installed professionally, you don't have anything else to worry about. Take the plow off whenever you can, because it's no fun driving around with it on the truck--all that weight out front really screws with the handling, and it's quite possible to bottom out the plow when going over humps in the road at speed.

Answer (score 4):

As@ mac has stated a plow will fit and the truck will push snow. The primary considerations are how often and how long are you going to plow. The longer and more frequently you plow the more the suspension and driveline  parts will be stressed. If you are just doing a few driveways you should have no problems. If you plan to plow commercially for long periods be prepared for repair bills. Have the trucks suspension, cooling and drive line inspected prior to having the plow instaled. Replace anything that is worn with heavy duty parts if they are available. If it has an automatic trans, consider getting an auxillary transmission cooler. When it comes to regular servicing follow the manufacturers guideline for severe duty use.